# Product Price based on currency in Magento

Tags: currency, magento-1.9

I need to set multiple product price for products in Magento based on currency.
I know that this can be done by creating multiple websites, but doing so only for a price attribute doesn't seem reasonable as everything expect that remains the same. Will also be problematic in terms of SEO.

Also came through an extension : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/currency-pricing.html, but doesn't looks promising based on the reviews.

Please share our suggestions on how this can be achieved without multiple website setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Auto Currency Switcher for this here is the [link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-extension-auto-currency-switcher-free/)

This extension uses the IP address of the country and display the currency according to the IP address. You just have to set up the Magento Cron to updated the currency and it will show the updated price of the products according to the country.

I think there is no need to create the multiple stores.

Hope it helps.

Thanks,